# Why EF inserted duplicates in the table?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

My model classes look like that:

```
 public class Car {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Make { get; set; }
        public string Model { get; set; }
    }
```

ApplicationDbContext class:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : DbContext {
    public DbSet<Car> Cars { get; set; }

    public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base("Rental") {
        Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = true;
    }
}
```

and the Seed method:

```
 protected override void Seed(ApplicationDbContext context) {

        context.Cars.AddOrUpdate(c => c.Id,
            new Car { Id = 1, Make = "BMW", Model = "750i" },
            new Car { Id = 2, Make = "Audi", Model = "A6" },
            new Car { Id = 3, Make = "Honda", Model = "Civic" }
            );
 }
```

After i execute(as many times as I want) `update-database` in Package Manager Console these object are once added to the database.

But after I added subclasses of Car class:

```
public class Car {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Make { get; set; }
    public string Model { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Rental> Rentals { get; set; }
}

public class JetCar : Car {
    public int Thrust { get; set; }//kN
}

public class Dragster : Car {
    public double Acceleration { get; set; }
}
```

then modified ApplicationDbContext:

```
 public class ApplicationDbContext : DbContext {
        public DbSet<Car> Cars { get; set; }
        public DbSet<JetCar> JetCars { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Dragster> Dragsters { get; set; }
        public ApplicationDbContext()
            : base("Rental") {
            Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = true;
        }
    }
```

and then Seed method

```
    protected override void Seed(ApplicationDbContext context) {

         context.Cars.AddOrUpdate(c => c.Id,
            new Car { Id = 1, Make = "BMW", Model = "750i" },
            new Car { Id = 2, Make = "Audi", Model = "A6" },
            new Car { Id = 3, Make = "Honda", Model = "Civic" }
            );

        context.Dragsters.AddOrUpdate(d => d.Id,
            new Dragster { Id = 4, Make = "Chevy", Acceleration = 3.23, }
            );

        context.JetCars.AddOrUpdate(d => d.Id,
           new JetCar { Id = 4, Make = "Jetty", Thrust = 89 }
           );

       }
```

Then after I executed `update-database` I ended up with duplicates of orignal Honda, BMW and Audi cars but with discriminator set to `Car`. Why is it so?  How to prevent this?

Answer (score 1):

You have duplicates because for Entity FrameWork, they are different.
When you use inheritance, EF keeps the same table, but with a Discriminator. Note that if there is no inheritance, there is no discriminator (no need for it).

The Cars you added first are the real `Car` type, but since inheritance doesn't exist (yet), EF doesn't add discriminator.
When you add `Dragster` and `JetCar`, EF now needs Discriminator.

Since your first added cars don't have discriminator, they are not recognized by EF. Now, EF is looking for Discriminator = 'Car' when querying the `Car` type.

You can either change your seed script and adjust some data manually (you can add manuel query in the migration that add the `Dragster` and `JetCar`)
 or you should swap inheritance for a link between 2 tables.

Comment: Thank you, but why EF didn't set discriminator for already existing records upon `update-database` command? Is there a reason for it or they forgot to implement this feature?

Comment: Because EF doesn't know what it was before the update-database. That's your job to define what Discriminator should be the 'old' Cars. Maybe they're all 1 type, maybe they're all the other, maybe there are some of both...

Answer (score 0):

You have to test as shown below for all your seeds objects.

```
var car1 = context.Cars.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Make == " BMW ");

if(car1 == null)
{
    context.Cars.Add(new Car { Id = 1, Make = "BMW", Model = "750i" });
}
```